# Как сделать так, чтобы программа работала после выбора нового файла

Tags: python, pyqt5, matplotlib

У меня есть программа с интерфейсом pyqt5. Изначально я выбираю через кнопку путь к файлу базы данных, потом нажимаю "построить график" в каждой из вкладок и в них всех строится графики через matplotlib. Но если я выбираю другой файл, после того как графики построил, и нажимаю "построить график" еще раз, то программа ничего не выполняет.

Как сделать так, чтобы после нажатия "построить график" программа строила новые графики по новой бд из нового файла?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Код большой и может быть непонятный :С

```
import sys  # sys нужен для передачи argv в QApplication
import os  # Отсюда нам понадобятся методы для отображения содержимого директорий
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
import design2  # Это наш конвертированный файл дизайна
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QSizePolicy, QVBoxLayout, QMessageBox, QWidget
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5 import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
from create_Graph import getGraph


class MyMplCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, fig, parent=None):
        self.fig = fig
        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, self.fig)
        FigureCanvas.setSizePolicy(self, QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)

class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, design2.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)  # Это нужно для инициализации нашего дизайна
        self.EnterBD_2.clicked.connect(self.getFileName)
        self.Button1.clicked.connect(self.getFirst)
        self.Button2.clicked.connect(self.getSecond)
        self.Button3.clicked.connect(self.getThird)
        self.Button4.clicked.connect(self.getFourth)
        self.wb_path = ""
        self.strError = ""
        self.WindowError = QMessageBox()

    def Error(self):
        msg = True
        if (self.wb_path == ""):
            self.showError("Спочатку оберіть файл бази даних")
            self.WindowError.show()
            msg = False
        elif(self.wb_path[-4:] != 'xlsx'):
            self.showError("Оберіть файл формату xlsx")
            self.WindowError.show()
            msg = False
        return msg

    def showError(self, str):
        self.WindowError.setIcon(QMessageBox.Critical)
        self.WindowError.setWindowTitle("Помилка!")
        self.WindowError.setText(str)
        self.WindowError.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok)

    def getFileName(self):
        wb_path = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Оберіть базу даних")
        self.wb_path = wb_path[0]

    def getFirst(self, Graph):
        if(self.Error()):
            Graph = getGraph(self.wb_path)
            self.fig = Graph.printGraphFirst()
            self.widget = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.widget)
            # получение объекта класса холста с нашим рисунком
            self.canavas = MyMplCanvas(self.fig)
            # Размещение экземпляра класса холста в шаблоне размещения
            self.widget.addWidget(self.canavas)
            # получение объекта класса панели управления холста
            self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canavas, self)
            # Размещение экземпляра класса панели управления в шаблоне размещения
            self.widget.addWidget(self.toolbar)

    def getSecond(self, Graph):
        if(self.Error()):
            Graph = getGraph(self.wb_path)
            self.fig = Graph.printGraphSecond()
            self.widget_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.widget_2)
            # получение объекта класса холста с нашим рисунком
            self.canavas_2 = MyMplCanvas(self.fig)
            # Размещение экземпляра класса холста в шаблоне размещения
            self.widget_2.addWidget(self.canavas_2)
            # получение объекта класса панели управления холста
            self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canavas_2, self)
            # Размещение экземпляра класса панели управления в шаблоне размещения
            self.widget_2.addWidget(self.toolbar)

    def getThird(self, Graph):
        if(self.Error()):
            Graph = getGraph(self.wb_path)
            self.fig = Graph.printGraphThird()
            self.widget_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.widget_3)
            # получение объекта класса холста с нашим рисунком
            self.canavas_3 = MyMplCanvas(self.fig)
            # Размещение экземпляра класса холста в шаблоне размещения
            self.widget_3.addWidget(self.canavas_3)
            # получение объекта класса панели управления холста
            self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canavas_3, self)
            # Размещение экземпляра класса панели управления в шаблоне размещения
            self.widget_3.addWidget(self.toolbar)

    def getFourth(self, Graph):
        if(self.Error()):
            Graph = getGraph(self.wb_path)
            self.fig = Graph.printGraphFourth()
            self.widget_4 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.widget_4)
            # получение объекта класса холста с нашим рисунком
            self.canavas_4 = MyMplCanvas(self.fig)
            # Размещение экземпляра класса холста в шаблоне размещения
            self.widget_4.addWidget(self.canavas_4)
            # получение объекта класса панели управления холста
            self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canavas_4, self)
            # Размещение экземпляра класса панели управления в шаблоне размещения
            self.widget_4.addWidget(self.toolbar)

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)  # Новый экземпляр QApplication
    window = Window()  # Создаём объект класса ExampleApp
    window.show()  # Показываем окно
    app.exec_()  # и запускаем приложение

if __name__ == '__main__':  # Если мы запускаем файл напрямую, а не импортируем
    main()  # то запускаем функцию main())
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: @S.Nick не думаю, что возможно сделать "минимальный пример" с этого всего, как вы себе это представляете?

Comment: я пока что не представляю, как вам помочь глядя на то, что вы опубликовали.

Comment: Непонятные строки с `self.widget = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.widget)` и ему подобные (`self.widget_2`, `self.widget_3`, ...) в текущем коде оно не должно работать, ведь при первом обращении `self.widget` (и ему подобные) еще не существуют в атрибутах `Window`